# [FATAL]RESULT=-1&RESPMSG=Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://payflowpro.paypal.com/

Tags: paypal

My client can’t hit paypal from CRM.

We are getting the following error:

The following information was included with the event:

Transaction Errors from PayFlow Submit Transactions = Message 1

[FATAL]RESULT=-1&RESPMSG=Failed to connect to host Input Server Uri = https://payflowpro.paypal.com/

I have already done the following:

1. Go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA and verify "Network Services" has Read permission to "MachineKeys" folder. If not, add it.
2. Enabled TLS 1.0 in IIS Crypto

Awaiting your response.
Regards,
Pankaj